# 'They told me that I will/would not be employed from Monday.' Which is correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense, subordinate-clauses

Consider the case where I am talking (about my being dismissed) on the previous Thursday. My work will stop at a time still in the future and it appears that 'will' can be used. But by a rule I have come across, it should be 'would' ... but I don't understand the logic behind this.

***Why*** does a main clause in the past always force a subordinate future clause to use the 'past tense'?

Or is this just a rule one has to learn...?

Comment: This is not relevant to what the question is about, but the sentence is syntactically ambiguous; the ambiguity would be avoided by saying 'be unemployed' rather than 'not be employed'.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you are referring to is called the **backshift.** In general, if one is reporting what someone said in the past, then every verb is shifted one level back in time. However, if a certain condition holds, then the backshift is optional. That condition is this ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p. 156):

> It must be reasonable to assume that the temporal relation between the
> situation and the reporter's time of utterance<sup>1</sup> is the same as that between
> the situation and the original time of utterance.

<sup><sup>1</sup>CGEL actually says 'deictic time' instead of 'time of utterance'. This distinction is unimportant for our purposes here. In any case, the deictic time is very often precisely the time of utterance.</sup>

So, for example, provided that it is still the case now that Jill has too many commitments, both of the following are acceptable:

*Jill said she **had** too many commitments.

Jill said she **has** too many commitments.*

Provided the condition quoted above is satisfied, there are various factors that affect the decision of whether or not to backshift, including (CGEL, pp. 157–158)

**(a) Reporter's attitude to the content**

If I endorse the content of what I'm reporting, then the non-backshifted version is more likely than if I don't.

*She said she **doesn't** need it, so I'll let Bill have it.*           [accepted: non-backshifted]
*She said there **was** plenty left, but there s hardly any.*              [rejected: backshifted]

**(b) Focus on original**

If the focus is on the original utterance (or belief), and there is a contrast between 'then' and 'now', then the backshifted version is favored.

Consider the backshifted sentence

*I thought it **was** mine.*

> One context for this is where it has just been established that it **is**
> mine: *thought* would here be strongly stressed, indicating a contrast
> between past thinking and present knowing (of the same proposition).
> Another context is where it has just been established (or claimed)
> that it is not mine: here the contrast is between what I thought in the past and what is known/claimed in the present.

**(c) Present perfect reporting clause**

Because the present perfect focuses on the present rather than the past, it tends to favor the non-backshifted version. So for example we'd have

*She said she **couldn't** afford it.*

But if instead we use the present perfect, we are more likely to drop the backshift:

*She has said she **can't** afford it*.

**(d) Simplification**

> Where the original utterance or belief is in the present tense, the
> backshifted and non-backshifted versions differ merely in primary
> tense, preterite vs present. But where the original is in the simple
> preterite they differ as preterite perfect vs simple preterite, i.e. as
> compound vs simple tense. In this case the non-backshifted version may
> be preferred precisely for its greater simplicity.